# Join additional data from pivot table to Kohana's ORM object

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

Firstly i need to describe my db tables:

```
+----------+     +----------------+      
| orders   |     | order_products |      +--------------+
+----------+     +----------------+      | products     |
| id       |-----| order_id       |      +--------------+
| date     |     | product_id     |------| id           |
| customer |     | quantity       |      | title        |
+----------+     +----------------+      | price        |
                                         +--------------+
```

I use kohana ORM to get orders:  `$orders=ORM::factory('Order')->find_all();`
Then get related products: `$products=$order->products->find_all();`
and when i want to display product, all product columns work fine
for example `$product->title`, but I want to get quantity in from `$product` (`$product->quantity`).

Is it possible to get this `quantity` field in `$product` object using Kohana's ORM?
If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Although it may be possible to get, it is not guaranteed and also impossible to set. This question has been asked in the Kohana forums as well. The way to solve this is to change the `has_many_through` to two `has_many` relationships. So orders has_many order_products belongs to products (or the other way round)

Comment: Unfortunately you have to create a new model, `Model_Order_Product`, and add an `id` as a primary key to the table as Kohana also does not support compound primary keys. You can then create 2 has many relations, one as `products through order_products` and one `order_products` - pointing to the actual `Model_Order_Product`